# How to represent this in a table?

Tags: database, database-normalization, database-table

I have a collection of data like so

```
Programme title |  Episode  |  Subtitle  |  Performers  |  Description
```

Initially I normalised this into two table like so

```
PROGRAMME

progid  |  progtitle  |  description

EPISODE

epid  |  progid  |  episode  |  subtitle  |  description
```

I'm thinking I'd like to represent the performers in another table though, but not sure how to represent it. From what I can tell the following relationships exist

- One to Many: A programme can have many performers
- One to Many: A performer could feature in many programmes

I'm not sure how I would represent this?

**EDIT**  Ah I see so I'd actually have tables like this for example?

```
PERFORMER

performerid  |  performer

PROGRAMME

progid  |  progtitle  |  description

EPISODE

epid  |  progid  |  episode  |  subtitle  |  description

PROG_PERFORMER

progid  |  performerid
```

Comment: The PROG_PERFORMER table should be EPISODE_PERFORMER. If the performers change per episode, and you change the PROG_PERFORMER table, that will change performers for all episodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's many-to-many.  One performer can be in multiple programs, and one program can have multiple performers.

There's plenty of information on the net (and in textbooks) about setting up many-to-may relationships. One such resource is here:

http://www.tekstenuitleg.net/en/articles/software/database-design-tutorial/many-to-many.html

Really, though it should be

- A Program has a one-many relationship with episodes
- An episode has a many-many relationship with performers.

This is enough to create a query that will list all performer/show/episode relationships.

Answer (score 2):

Also, performers can change between episodes

Comment: Good catch.  +1.  I thought of that but after I'd posted, but you posted it before I could add it to my answer.

Comment: then create your relation table with `performerid` and `epid`

Answer (score 1):

beside performer table you have to create a relation table

performer table

```
performerid | name | ...
```

relation table

```
performerid | progid
```